# Peskin p152: Summing over Colors in Decay Rate

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In Peskin & Schroeder, section 5.3, there is a calculation towards the cross section σ and decay rate Γ for the process:

e+, e-  <—>  Bound state of μ+ μ-.

Where the cross section is applicable to the forward process and the decay rate is applicable to the reverse process.

I’m fine to this point.

Following this, on page 152, the authors generalize the discussion to the following process, where ‘j’ indexes to color:

e+, e-  <—->  Bound state of q<sub>j</sub>+, q<sub>j</sub>-

Where q indicates a particular flavor of quark or antiquark.

The authors claim that, for this process, the new cross section is 3σ, and the new decay rate is 3Γ, with σ and Γ calculated in the same method as in the original muon process (with respect to the different bound state wavefunction). The factor of 3 comes from summing over colors.

I’m with the author on the factor of 3 for the cross section, but not on the decay rate.

On the cross section, we need to sum the probabilities for the 3 colors j, which yields the factor of 3.

On the decay rate, I would have thought that we need to **average** over the 3 colors, and not sum. Thus, I would think that you do not need a factor of 3 in front of Γ.

I can’t tell if I am misunderstanding something, or if there is an error here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe I’ve figured this out. The bound state wave function used in the formula is normalized for a **particular** color of quark, not the aggregate of all three. The decay rate thus has to be multiplied by three to account for this properly.